# Create / Edit / View the same form with Angular

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am creating a slightly elaborated form with Angular. This form can be submitted, then modified or simply displayed (with everything in read-only for example).

For now I have 3 templates with 3 controllers for each action (submit / edit / view) and the form is added as a partial (ng-include). The form has also its own controller. Is it the right way?

Also, should I make the form's controller the children of the templates' controllers or the opposite? I am using the same model for each action behind the form and I guess it should be injected through the template's controller.

It's my very first attempt to do this and I would like to have a few advice's and hints since I am afraid of going the wrong way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yo can use different template for each of them with single controller, different controller for each of them is not a good idea because there may be some common function in them  then you need to write that function in each of them.

you can use common model for them,i am doing the same.

Comment: The form has actually its own controller already and only one, this is actually not the question exactly. Above that form though there is a page and for that page I have a different controller.

Comment: The question is more around the concept of controller/template hierarchy and should the form controller be a child of the main controller or not.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is promising solutions to what you are looking for 
can you try this http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form